# Middleware to Bring 3D Meshes into OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl, c++, opengl-es, models, importing

Say I develop a game for mobile platform running OpenGL ES 2.0. I have done 2D part, and now I wish to import some 3D objects.

The imported 3D objects must contain the following:

- Vertices positions
- Normals
- UVs
- Texturing information
- Animation information
- Collision mesh
- Maybe some other things...

I am aware, that I could and (maybe should) create my own file format that brings these data from 3D authoring application (3ds Max, Maya, Softimage) into the game.

However, doing so from scratch is going to be really be a lot of work. Therefore, is there any available solution/middleware, that will let me import 3d meshes into my game, ready to use?

The solution/middleware should be:

- easy to use
- easy to port
- efficient
- not consuming too much memory with unnecessary things
- containing all the above mentioned features plus things I haven't considered yet

Programming language is: C++.

Currently, I'm developing under Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, and OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator.

Later, the product will be ported to iOS and possibly Android.

Comment: @Tetrad: Thanks for little adjustments to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [AssImp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/index.html).  It's an open C++ model loader that supports a bunch of different formats.

Comment: +1 for great comment. Hi and thanks. I will try it. I will keep this thread open, to see if any other alternatives are going to be suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I checked AssImp, and it looks quite well. It is always complex decision whether to program own 3d file format, or to use import library like AssImp.